# How do I run a terminal command within PHP?

Tags: php, command-line, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm writing an in-house module to generate a small LaTeX PDF.  Within the module, how do I use PHP to utilize the command line?

Comment: Drupal 9 doesn't exist, yet. You probably wanted to tag the question with drupal-6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the function: [passthru()](http://mx.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
if you want to directly send the output of your command.

Or if you run your command that command creates a file in the sever and then you send that file to the user use the command [exec()](http://mx.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: The link for the passthru documentation page is http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php.